# java sudoku solver values not changing

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

My indexoutofbounds issues has been solved but not my program compiles but prints out an unchanged puzzle.. not sure where I am going wrong?? The original puzzle read roms std input has 0s in the place of an 'empty'cell of a sudoku puzzle. I've included my arraylist initialiser as well.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> create(){

    ArrayList<Integer> possible = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
        possible.add(i);
    }
    return possible;
  }
  public sudoku( int size )
  {
    SIZE = size;
    N = size*size;

    Grid = new int[N][N];
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
        for( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
            Grid[i][j] = 0;
   }

  public void solve()
  { 
    int a, b, c, d, i, j, k, l; 

    int count = 0;
    int value= 0;

    for(i=0; i<N;i++){
        for(j=0; j<N;j++){  
            if(Grid[i][j]==0){

                ArrayList<Integer> possible = create();

                //check row             
                for(a=0; a<N;a++){
                    for(b=0; b<N; b++){  
                        if(Grid[a][0]==possible.get(a)){
                            possible.set(a, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //check column
                for(c=0; c<N;c++){
                    for(d=0; d<N;d++){  
                        if(Grid[0][d]==possible.get(d)){
                            possible.set(d,0);
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(k=0; k<9; k++){
                    if(possible.get(k)!=0){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if(count==1){
                    for(l=0; l<9; l++){
                        if(possible.get(l)!=0){
                            value=possible.get(l);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Grid[i][j]=value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't see where you initialized the size of Grid, so it's more difficult to help you. (Or maybe impossible to help you)

Comment: I'm not real excited by _Grid[i][0]_ that I see a few times...  That isn't your problem... yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your problem, you're using the i and j variables as indices more than once in nested for loops:

```
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { // **** you use "i" it here
     for (j = 0; j < N; j++) { // **** and "j" here
        if (Grid[i][j] == 0) {

           ArrayList<Integer> possible = create();

           for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { // **** and again here
              for (j = 0; j < N; j++) { // **** and again here
                 if (Grid[i][0] == possible.get(i)) {
                    possible.set(i, 0);
                 }
              }
           }

           for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { // **** and again here
              for (j = 0; j < N; j++) { // **** and again here
                 if (Grid[0][j] == possible.get(i)) {
                    possible.set(i, 0);
                 }
              }
           }

           // ....

           Grid[i][j] = value;
        }
     }
  }
```

By advancing the indices from within the for loop, you risk going past the maximal index, and so by the time you reach the bottom, your i and j have been incremented all the way to 9, past the size of the row and column. You should almost never change a for loop index from inside the for loop. You will want to re-write this code.

Edit: it's even simpler than that: You're checking i after a for loop has concluded, so that i is the value of the top bound.  Run this to see what I mean:

```
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        System.out.println("C) i = " + i);
     }
     System.out.println("D) i = " + i);
  }
```

Comment: The i and j are set back to zero for each for loop, so I don't see where the error is, can you be more specific?  Or are you saying the i and j being used in the last statement are not the ones he is intending to use? (ie they are the ones from the most recent for loop rather than the first one?)

Comment: actually he doesn't even have to nest i, but after a for loop has concluded, the index variable is the max value of the loop.

Comment: out of bounds is solved now! my next issue is that none of the values are changing...

Comment: @YoussefG. - The innermost loop stops when `i < N` is false, that is when `i==N`.  So after the innermost loop the values of i and j are both N.  Then accessing `Grid[i][j]` is invalid as the largest valid indices for `Grid` are `N-1` for both places

Comment: Yes, I see it now. got lost in all the braces! Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: any clues as to why the cells aren't changing values?

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out possible.get(0) to make sure it's not empty! If that throws the error, then there you go!

Or, you could try a try statement in between loops to figure out which part throws it, as below.

```
try{
    ArrayList<Integer> possible = create();
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
         System.out.println(1);
}
try{
                //check row             
                for(i=0; i<N;i++){
                    for(j=0; j<N;j++){  
                        if(Grid[i][0]==possible.get(i)){
                            possible.set(i, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
         System.out.println(2);
}
try{
                //check column
                for(i=0; i<N;i++){
                    for(j=0; j<N;j++){  
                        if(Grid[0][j]==possible.get(i)){
                            possible.set(i,0);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
         System.out.println(3);
}
try{
                for(k=0; k<9; k++){
                    if(possible.get(k)!=0){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
         System.out.println(4);
}
try{
                if(count==1){
                    for(l=0; l<9; l++){
                        if(possible.get(l)!=0){
                            value=possible.get(l);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
         System.out.println(5);
}
try{
                Grid[i][j]=value;}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
         System.out.println(6);
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessary - an exception's stacktrace will tell you exactly where it was thrown from.

Comment: my program compiles but the empty values in the sudoku puzzle (which are technically 0s) are not changing